# How to add variables to a dataframe using paste?

Tags: r, paste, dataframe

I have a set of R objects named `c1,c2,c3,...,c10` each with same length and like to form a dataframe from these objects. I could do it by `df<-data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10`). Is there a more efficient way of doing this, perhaps using `paste`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the title of this question is inaccurate - since use of paste() is described as being optional in the body of the question, and it's not paste that does the work to form the data.frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data.frame(sapply(paste("c",1:10,sep=""),get))
```

or,

```
data.frame(mget(paste("c",1:10,sep=""),.GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: If get is the answer chances are that you're asking the wrong question.